# asp hidden field postback value

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I have a hidden field that I assign a disabled check box value to for after post back.  Works just fine in Chrome and Firefox.  IE, however, does not hold this value after post back. Suggestions?

ASPX.VB

Page_PreRender:

```
chkbxEmailPhone.Attributes.Add("onChange", "fnDisableChkBox(this);return buttonClick(this);")


If hidChkBxValue.Value = String.Empty Then
        hidChkBxValue.Value = "false"
    End If
    chkbxEmailPhone.Checked = CBool(hidChkBxValue.Value)
```

ASPX

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkbxEmailPhone" runat="server" Text="Include Telephone & E-Mail" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="bold tdfont10" Value=""></asp:CheckBox>

<asp:HiddenField ID="hidChkBxValue" runat="server" Value="" />
```

```
function fnDisableChkBox(){

    if(document.getElementById("chkbxEmailPhone").checked == true){
        document.getElementById("hidChkBxValue").value = "true";
        }
    else{
        document.getElementById("hidChkBxValue").value = "false";
        }

   document.getElementById("chkbxEmailPhone").disabled = true;
    }

</script>
```

Comment: It's all messed up I would say. What you are doing in `buttonClick` method? Why you have `AutoPostBack="true"` for your checkbox? Whatever code you have mentioned in `ASPX.VB` section is that inside _Page_Load_ event? What you are trying to do exactly?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do, but you know that a disabled form control is not submitted via "normal" forms processing, right (submit button)? Try setting it to read only instead, see if that works. The expected control being "missing" might be confusing something in the pipeline. I can't tell how your form is submitted since you didn't post all your code. Also, as noted by Rahul, the autopostback might also not be something you want on that checkbox.

Comment: Sorry, should have gave more information.  I only posted code related to the situation. The aspx.vb code is in Pre_Render.  The check box will determine if a specific column in my datagrid is visible.  The user checks the box and the page does a postback.  The javascript function disables that checkbox while the postback is occuring, to avoid double clicking, etc. and stores that checkbox value into the hidden field. I am using a hidden field because disabled checkboxs dont hold their value after postback.

Comment: Once the page reloads I take that hidden value and assign it to the checkbox.  There is just a simple if statement in my datagrid_itemdatabound to show/hide the column based off if the checkbox is checked or not.  Like I said before, everything works great in Chrome and Firefox.  I'm just not sure what about it is causing problems in IE.

Comment: Also, the buttonClick method just shows a custom loading image, to let the  user know some event is occuring.